# need to get quotes in front of text without using any escape charecters and gsub

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I have a file called `tst.csv` with the below content

```
"FORESS INTL PTN "A" (208)"
```

Need to get the below output  and the requirement is we should not be using any escape character (`\`) and also `gsub`/`sub` only needs to be used to achieve the below expected output - as external program that we are using  is not be decode the backslash character.

Expected o/p

```
"FORESS INTL PTN ""A"" (208)"
```

Tried the below command

```
awk '{gsub(/"/,"&&");gsub(/^""|""$/,"")}1' tst.csv
```

I get the below o/p

```
FORESS INTL PTN ""A"" (208)
```

But not able to get double quotes in front of the text nor at the end of the line.

Comment: rewrite the second gsub as `gsub(/^"|"$/, "")`

Comment: `awk -v dq='"' '{gsub(/"/,"&&"); gsub(/^""|""$/, dq)}1'` is another option here.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
gsub(/"/, "&&"); gsub(/^"|"$/, "")
```

To get a `"` into an awk variable without using a backslash, you can always do:

```
awk -v q='"' ...
```

Or in `awk` (assuming an ASCII-based system):

```
BEGIN {q = sprintf("%c", 34)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either replace the double `""` at the start and end with `"` using

```
gsub(/^""|""$/, "\"")
```

(although this uses an escape character) or remove only the outermost `"` at the start and end using

```
gsub(/^"|"$/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below sed command and it worked fine

```
  echo '"FORESS INTL PTN "A" (208)"'| sed "s/\"A\"/\"&\"/g"
```

otput

```
    "FORESS INTL PTN ""A"" (208)"
```

Python

```
raveen:/var/tmp$ cat o.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('p.txt','r')
for i in k:
    print i.replace('"A"','""A""')
```